# cooldown for twitch bot

Tags: javascript, bots, chat, twitch

I wan't my bot to answer the "!help" command that people will type on chat but only once every 60 seconds

````js
require('dotenv').config();

const tmi = require('tmi.js');

const client = new tmi.Client({
    channels: [ 'test' ],
    identity: {
        username: process.env.TWITCH_BOT_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.TWITCH_OATH_TOKEN
    }
});

client.connect();

client.on('message', (channel, tags, message, self) => {
    const send = message === "!help"

        if ( !send ) return; 
         {
            client.say(channel, `This message shouldn't send more then once eveyr 60 seconds`)
         }

    console.log(`${tags['display-name']}: ${message}`);
}); ```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can use `new Date()` to get the current datetime. And `new Date().getTime()` gives you a number of milliseconds since epoch (since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).

```
// get the current time
const timeNow = new Date().getTime()
```

Every time you send a `'!help'` response you save the current time.

```
// the time of the last help message
let lastHelpTime = 0

// ... later when sending the message
// update the last help message time
lastHelpTime = timeNow
```

On every `'!help'` command you compare `timeNow` against the saved value `lastHelpTime` to avoid sending again within a minute. To allow a new response the time difference `timeNow - lastHelpTime` must be greater than `60` seconds, but because we have to compare milliseconds, it means the difference must be greater than `60 * 1000` milliseconds.

```
// check if at least 1 minute has elapsed since the last help message
if (timeNow - lastHelpTime > 60 * 1000) //...
```

Combined all together in your original code

```
// the time of the last help message
let lastHelpTime = 0

client.on('message', (channel, tags, message, self) => {
    const send = message === "!help"

    if ( !send ) return;

    // get the current time
    const timeNow = new Date().getTime()
    // check if at least 1 minute has elapsed since the last help message
    if (timeNow - lastHelpTime > 60 * 1000) {
        // update the last help message time
        lastHelpTime = timeNow
        // post the help message in chat
        client.say(channel, `This is the help message`)
    }

    console.log(`${tags['display-name']}: ${message}`);
});
```